# Matriz como parámetro C++

Tags: c++

Estimados estoy intentando enviar un arreglo dinámico como parámetro a una función en C++ pero me dice como error que la variable N está fuera de contexto o no está definida, como puedo resolver ese error? Quedo atento. Saludos.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void generarArreglo(int matriz[n][n]){
  srand(time(NULL));
  for(int i=0;i<=6;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<=6;j++){
      matriz[i][j]=rand()%99+1;
    }
  }
}

void imprimirArreglo(int matriz[n][n]){
  for(int i=0;i<=6;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<=6;j++){
      cout<<matriz[i][j]<<"\t";
    }
    cout<<endl;
  }
}

int main(){

  int n;    
  cin >> n;
  int matriz[n][n];
  generarArreglo(matriz);
  imprimirArreglo(matriz);
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error se está produciendo aquí:

```
void generarArreglo(int matriz[n][n]){ // <<--- AQUI!!!
  // ...
}

void imprimirArreglo(int matriz[n][n]){ // <<--- AQUI!!!
```

Y el motivo es que `n` no existe para esas funciones. Si fuese un valor constante y conocido en tiempo de compilación podrías parchear el código tal que:

```
const int n = 5;

void generarArreglo(int matriz[n][n]){ // OK
  // ...
}
```

Pero no es el caso. Como ya te han propuesto una solución usando una matriz a base de punteros dobles yo te propongo una solución similar con punteros simples... o con un único vector. La ventaja de usar contendores de la STL es que evitas lidiar con la memoria dinámica, lo cual suele suponer, como norma general, un gran alivio:

```
void generarArreglo(std::vector<int>& matriz){
  srand(time(NULL));
  for( int i=0; i<matriz.size(); i++)
    matriz[i]=rand()%99+1;
}

void imprimirArreglo(std::vector<int>& matriz, int n){
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
      cout<<matriz[i*n+j]<<'\t';
    }
    cout<<'\n';
  }
}

int main(){
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  std::vector<int> matriz(n*n,0);
  generarArreglo(matriz);
  imprimirArreglo(matriz, n);
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Y lo mismo se podría conseguir con un puntero simple... las ventajas sobre un puntero doble son, básicamente, dos:

- Únicamente se requiere una reserva y una liberación
- La memoria está toda agrupada, lo que favorece el uso de la caché del sistema.

Ejemplo con puntero simple:

```
void generarArreglo(int* matriz, int length){
  srand(time(NULL));

  while( length-- )
  {
    *matriz=rand()%99+1;
    ++matriz;
  }
}

void imprimirArreglo(int* matriz, int n){
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<n;++j,++matriz){
      cout<<*matriz<<'\t';
    }
    cout<<'\n';
  }
}

int main(){

  int n;
  cin >> n;
  int* matriz = new int[n*n];
  generarArreglo(matriz, n*n);
  imprimirArreglo(matriz, n);
  delete[] matriz;

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Falta la versión en que se recibe la matriz por referencia.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, y la explicación. Me quedó muy claro !! @eferion

Answer (score 2):

Mi Solución:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void generarArreglo(int **matriz, int rows, int cols){
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){
            matriz[i][j]=rand()%99+1;
        }
    }
}

void imprimirArreglo(int **matriz, int rows, int cols){
    for(int i=0;i< rows;i++){
        for(int j=0;j< cols;j++){
            cout<<matriz[i][j]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int rows , cols;
    rows = cols = n;
    int** matriz = new int*[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        matriz[i] = new int[cols];
    generarArreglo(matriz, rows, cols);
    imprimirArreglo(matriz, rows, cols);
    return 0;
}
```

Entrada:

```
4
```

Salida:

```
98  79  6   19  
11  2   96  95  
63  33  11  93  
80  36  70  50
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu código

```
int matriz[n][n];
```

no es válido en C++. Las dimensiones de una matriz han de ser constantes, no variables. Tendrás que declararla como puntero, y reservar memória sobre la marcha:

```
int *matriz;
matriz = calloc( n, n );
```

Y tendrás que modificar todas tus funciones, claro.

**EDITO**

Para acceder mediante punteros, es igual (estoy seguro en C, echadme a los lobos si en C++ no pasa lo mismo):

```
int *matriz = calloc( n, n );

matriz[0][0] = *matriz;
matriz[0][1] = matriz[2];
matriz[1][0] = matriz[n] = matriz[n][0]
```

Si en lugar del feo y sucio **C++** usaras **C** plano, **SI** podrías usar variables para declarar arrays ( en C11 ).

En **C**, un `array` y un `puntero` son equivalentes. Si declarar un `array[]`, el compilador reserva memoria para el tamaño indicado, y realmente lo que tu usas es un **puntero** a esa memoria.

**EDITO 2**

¿ Porqué usas 2 `for` anidados ?
Con que uses

```
int *idx;
for( idx = matriz; idx < n * n; ++ idx ) {
 . . .
}
```

Los `array` y los bloques de memoria devueltos por `calloc()`, `malloc()` y similares **son contiguos en memoria**. Simplemente, imagina que es un `array[]` de una sola dimension, pero mucho mas largo.

**EDITO 3**

Por tus comentarios, te veo con ganas de aprender.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void generarArreglo( int *matrix, int size ){
  srand( time( NULL ) );

  while( size -- )
    *matrix++ = rand( ) % 99 + 1;
}

void imprimirArreglo( int *matrix, int ancho, int size ) {
  int pos = 0;

  while( size-- ) {
    ::std::cout << "[" << *matrix++ << "]";
    if( ! ( ++pos % ancho ) )
      ::std::cout << ::std::endl;
  }

 ::std::cout << ::std::endl;
}

int main( ) {
  int *matriz;
  int n;

  ::std::cin >> n;
  matriz = (int *)calloc( n, n );

  generarArreglo( matriz, n * n );
  imprimirArreglo( matriz, n, n * n );

  system( "pause" );
  return 0;
}
```

Versión 1.0. Se admiten parches.

**PD** - Por código como ese, se dice que **C**/**C++** son de **solo escritura**.

Comment: tendré que declarar los parámetros como punteros ??

Comment: Creo que como array también te valdrán, son intercambiables ( en C, en C++ no estoy seguro ). De todas formas, con punteros es más facil que todo lo que has liado en tu código.

Comment: de está forma como puedo hacer referencia a un elemento dentro de la matriz ?

Comment: Al final declararlo como array es lo mismo que declararlo como puntero, la notación de arreglo es solo "syntactic sugar", por lo tanto, creo que tiene razón @Trauma, deberías intentar con `malloc()`, `calloc()`. Te podría ayudar mucho investigar acerca de **Asignación Dinámica de Memoria**

Comment: la funcion calloc a que librería pertenece ??

Comment: `calloc`, al igual que `malloc`, `free`, etc pertenece a `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: si yo quiero que la matriz (puntero) sea de un tamaño dinamico, (dato que ingresa por pantalla), de que tipo debe ser n?

Comment: Mira el código que te puse. Puntero a int => `int *matriz;`

Comment: Una consulta, por qué usas `calloc` en ves de `new`?

Comment: @Xam Aunque hay algunas mínimas diferencias, la verdad es que fue por despiste. Estoy más cómodo en C, y se me *traspapeló*. Tal y como sospechas, se podría usar `matriz = new int[n][n];`.

Answer (score 0):

Propongo que se declare la matriz de la forma:

```
int mat[n][n];
```

Solamente como una buena práctica, porque si se declara de forma dinámica, aunque esto se hace de forma automática, es recomendable que al final se libere manualmente la memoria que se pidió al sistema, sin embargo, de esta forma, no hace falta. Lo otro que propongo es que al pasar la matriz como parámetro como un puntero + las dimensiones, esto hace que sea mucho más flexible a la hora de trabajar con la matriz si le queremos hacer cambios posteriores en sus dimensiones.

Comment: Eso que comentas es VLA ("Variable-Length Array) y **no** es una característica contemplada en el estándar de C++ (sin embargo sí lo está en el estándar C99 de C). Esto quiere decir que si te funciona es porque el que diseñó el copilador así lo quiso... pero lo mismo con otro compilador no tienes tanta suerte

Comment: @eferion: Eso está claro